# Change vue router route without changing the URL

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In my frontend I want to redirect the user to an error view in case the initialization went wrong. For this purpose I've prepare a special error view that could be called via a specific route. To improve UX I don't want to replace the url with something like `/error`, but I still want to take advantage of the vue router.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

There is a discussion in github: [change current component used by router-view without changing current URL](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/977)

However, the expecting function `replaceView` is still unavailable so far.

I have the exactly same requirement as yours, and I find a workaround:

I have a route component called `App.vue` (I use [Quasar Framework](https://quasar.dev)). Its template looks like:

```
<template>
  <div id="q-app">
    <div v-if="$store.state.g.errorState">
      <the-error-page>Error Message</the-error-page>
    </div>
    <router-view v-else />
  </div>
</template>
```

I use vuex's global store `state.g.errorState` to flag the error state. If it is true, display the error page, otherwise display the normal router view.

If I have a error in my page, I just commit the true value to `state.g.errorState`:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    // ...
  },
  beforeMount() {
    if (somethingWrong) {
      this.$store.commit('g/errorState', true)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Obviously, the `state.g.errorState` value should be restored to false every time the route changes:

```
const Router = new VueRouter({
  // ...
})

Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  store.commit('g/errorState', false)
  next()
})
```

Comment: Really good answer and it works well for error pages, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Working inside an axios interceptor, this did the trick for me (still a hack)

```
if (error.response.status === 404) {
      router.replace({ name: '404' });
      history.replaceState({}, "Not Found", error.response.request.responseURL)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `history.replaceState`. [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Example_of_pushState()_method) and [replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method) are [what Vue Router uses internally](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html) to manipulate the URL. Observe what happens to the address bar when you enter this line in your browser's console..

`history.replaceState({urlPath:'/some/page/on/stackoverflow'},"",'/some/page/on/stackoverflow')`

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to achieve is the other way. I want to change the router-view without changing the url in the adressbar.

Comment: @jimmy Yes I do get that. What I meant was to use `replaceState` to manually remove the `/error` part from your actual URL immediately after you navigate to your error view :)

Comment: That would be indeed an option. Thanks.

Comment: @jimmy I'm looking at your question again and I'm wondering why you can't just setup [an alias](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#alias) for your error view?

Comment: Why doing something simple when it could be achieved even more complex. Thanks, this is elegant.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

in router/index.js:

```js
{
  name: "error",
  path: "*",
  component: () => import("src/pages/error/404.vue"),
},
```

In component:

```js
this.$router.replace({
   name: "error",
   params: { 0: `/${this.$route.path}` },
   replace: true,
});
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the solution using vuex store. In store, I created a state variable *is404: false*. I also created a mutation to change it.
In my **App.vue** I import Error.page.vue, and I use it based on my *is404* variable:

```
<Error v-if="is404" />

<component v-else :is="currentLayout" />
```

Finally, in the **router.js** after I catch an error I set my *is404* variable to true:

```
$store.set("shared/is404", true);
```

Like that, when a user is typing URL which doesn't exist, he seems the error messgae, but the URL doesn't change.